# Apache httpd: How can I Deny from all, Allow from specifc IP addresses

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, httpd.conf, deny

Can someone take a look at the syntax of the code below and let me know if it is correct

-- my intention is to exclude the htaccess for the IP ranges specified in the 'Allow' part and rest of all should ask for authentication when they access the site.

This is simply 'denies' every one . IP range specified in Allow from should not ask for htaccess , But it asking for htaccess fro every one.

Can anyone confirm this, and help me to make this work:

```
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName EnterPassword
    AuthType Basic
    require valid-user
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 30.21.37.
    Allow from 113.11.23.23
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from All

AuthName "EnterPassword"
AuthUserFile /etc/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz
Satisfy Any
```

Comment: I have tried the above sequence of code still there is no luck. IPs allowed to exclude the htaccess are still asking authentication.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no overrides of Order and Deny?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to Allow from specifc IP address in htaccess.
Here is the best and easy solution

http://www.toshop.com/htaccess-generator.cfm

Just Select your desired option and click on generate.